# Enumerable.tolist return a Generic List

Tags: vb.net, linq

Please see the code below:

```
Public Shared Sub LinqTest()
        Dim t1 As New TestPerson
        t1.id = 1
        t1.name = "Ian"

        Dim t2 As New TestPerson
        t2.id = 2
        t2.name = "Lauren"

        Dim list As List(Of TestPerson) = New List(Of TestPerson)
        list.Add(t1)
        list.Add(t2)

        Dim list2 As List(Of TestPerson) = New List(Of TestPerson)
        list2.Add(t1)

        Dim linqresult = From p1 In list Join p2 In list2 On New With {Key p1.id, Key p1.name} Equals New With {Key p2.id, Key p2.name} Select p1.id, p1.name

    End Sub
```

I realize I can do this:

```
 Dim list3 As New List(Of TestPerson)
        For Each var In test
            Dim tyPerson As New TestPerson
            tyPerson.id = var.id
            tyPerson.name = var.name
            list3.Add(tyPerson)
        Next
```

Is it possible to use .ToList with a generic list?

**Update**
Following on from Ed Plunketts' comment; I have tried this:

```
 Dim linqresult As List(Of TestPerson) = test.ToList
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of <anonymous type>)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of com.Genie.PresentationLayer.Console.TestPerson)
```

I have also tried this:

```
   Dim linqresult = test.ToList
                For Each var As TestPerson In linqresult

                Next
```

The error I get is:

```
Value of type '<anonymous type> (line 36)' cannot be converted to 'com.Genie.PresentationLayer.Console.TestPerson
```

Comment: `linqresult = linqresult.ToList`

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, I do not believe that linqresult would be a generic list in your example?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, I have updated the question.

Comment: You've created an Anonymous Type, it cant know how to convert that to a specific type (`TestPerson`).  I think all you need is `Dim list3 = list.Intersect(list2).ToList()`

Comment: "Is it possible to use `.ToList` with a generic list?" Yes, in fact, it's _required_.  There is not a non-generic `ToList` extension method

Answer (score 0):

`ToList` is not your problem.  You are generating an *anonymous* type and trying to store that in a list of a *known* type.

Either change your Linq query to project to the known type

```
Dim linqresult = From p1 In list _
                 Join p2 In list2 _
                   On New With {Key p1.id, Key p1.name} _
                   Equals New With {Key p2.id, Key p2.name} _
                   Select New TestPerson With {Id = p1.id, Name = p1.name}
```

or

```
Dim linqresult = From p1 In list _
                 Join p2 In list2 _
                   On New With {Key p1.id, Key p1.name} _
                   Equals New With {Key p2.id, Key p2.name} _
                   Select p1
```

if you want the *actual* items from the list rather than *new* items.